# Oauth2 access token returns "invalid client" error

Tags: api, curl, oauth-2.0, access-token, zoho

I have a problem in getting access token. After getting auth code, when I called my get_access_token it returns "invalid_client" error. I researched about it but nothing helped me. Please, look at my code and help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.
Here is my code:

```
public function get_access_token($zoho_code)
{
    $headers = array(

    );
    $taskurl = 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token';
    $cdata = array(
        'code' => $zoho_code,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' =>  $this->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client_secret_id,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/callback.php',
        'scope' => 'ZohoMail.accounts.UPDATE,ZohoMail.accounts.READ,ZohoMail.partner.organization.READ,ZohoMail.partner.organization.UPDATE,ZohoMail.organization.accounts.CREATE,ZohoMail.organization.accounts.UPDATE,ZohoMail.organization.accounts.READ,ZohoMail.organization.domains.CREATE,ZohoMail.organization.domains.UPDATE,ZohoMail.organization.domains.DELETE,ZohoMail.organization.domains.READ',
        'state' => '55555sfdfsdfgbcv',

    );
    $curlresult = $this->docurl($taskurl, $cdata, $headers);

    return $curlresult;
}

public function docurl($taskurl, $cdata, $headers, $method = 'post',$sendjson=true) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    if ($method == 'get') {
        if ($cdata) {
            $query = '?' . http_build_query($cdata);
            $taskurl .= $query;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    } elseif ($method == 'delete') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    } elseif ($method == 'put') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    } elseif ($method == 'patch') {
        if($sendjson) $cdata = json_encode($cdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    } else {

        if($sendjson) $cdata = json_encode($cdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cdata);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $taskurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $information = curl_getinfo($ch);

    print_r($information);
    print_r($cdata);

    curl_close($ch);
    $resj = json_decode($res);
     return $resj;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I read your code correctly, you are sending your `client_secret` as part of a POST request body encoded as JSON.

You should make a POST request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body and you should include the `Authorization` header with the `client_secret` encoded in the Basic scheme. For more info, see the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3).

Comment: I tried what you wrote. It also doesn't work. And also in ZohoMail API documentation it is written that I should use it in this form:                                                           POST oauth/v2/token
HOST:: https://accounts.zoho.com

Query String:

https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token
?code=1000.****************************f160
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=1000.R2Z0W*********************Q5EN
&client_secret=39c**********************************921b
&redirect_uri=https://zylkerapps.com/oauth2callback
&scope=VirtualOffice.folders.READ

Answer (score 2):

You need to change accounts.zoho.com according to your data centre. For example accounts.zoho.in for India. You can see this in the URL of your Zoho web app. It is written in their docs [link](https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#multidc).